# Calling Rest API Java- Spring Boot with spring batch batch

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-mvc, batch-file

We are using Spring batch with Spring Boot. We have to read data from a CSV file, transform it and call Rest API to send data to different system. We are able to read CSV file but do not know how can we process data using RestAPI in chunk (Processing 100 records in one shot).  We have already gone through the https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/using-spring-batch-with-boot-to-consume-webservice-and-post-to-rest-api link which seems calling API for each record one by one.  Can we process our data in bulk (100 records at once)?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Can you make your question more focused somehow?  Saying, "I don't know how to process 100 records in one shot" is too broad.  A better question might be, "Can the Spring Batch Rest API process 100 records in a single method call?"  Even that doesn't seem like an ideal question for this site.  StackOverflow requires very specific questions.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We have a CSV file to read and call RestAPI to process data. We want to read data in chunk(100 at one time) and call RestAPI to process it. So do we need to iterate data one by one in write method of spring batch and call RestAPI for one by one?